# Call class method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, couchrest

I am using [couchrest_model](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model) in a Rails project, and I am trying to retrieve the server URL defined in couchdb.yml.

I can see that `server` is a class method defined in [connection.rb](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model/blob/master/lib/couchrest/model/connection.rb), but how can I access it in code? I am trying:

```
server = CouchRest::Model.server
```

but seeing the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `server' for CouchRest::Model:Module)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CouchRest::Model` is the namespace where `CouchRest::Model::Base` lives.

You are expected to create a model by inheriting from [`Base`](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model/blob/master/lib/couchrest/model/base.rb).

```
class Project < CouchRest::Model::Base
  use_database 'projects'
end
```

And because [`Connection`](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model/blob/master/lib/couchrest/model/connection.rb) is mixed into `Model::Base` (not `Model`) then you should be able to access it with

```
Project.server
```

where `Project` is your model name.

```
CouchRest::Model::Base.server
```

should also work but it's probably not the best solution because it's not model-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Having look at the code, server is defined in CouchRest::Model::Connection module, which is then included in CouchRest::Model::Base class. So, this should work:

```
server = CouchRest::Model::Base.server
```

Please note, that I don't know this gem does so this might not be its proper use. You should probably check documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

While couchrest_model does offer access to a `server` method, I wouldn't recommend trying to use it. Unlike a traditional ORM or RDMS, there is no reason why you can't have multiple servers accessed from the same project.

The `database` method provided for each model is the canonical source of connection details and is probably the most useful for performing CouchDB operations manually. A database object can also be accessed from model instances, which is especially useful when dealing with [proxied models](http://www.couchrest.info/model/proxying.html).

Given the model:

```
class Project < CouchRest::Model::Base
  use_database 'projects'
end
```

You could access the data as follows:

```
Project.database  # => Database object
Project.database.server.uri   # => Server URL
Project.database.root  # => Database URL
```

And in the case of a proxied model:

```
company = Company.first
company.invoices.database.root   # => Database URL
```